# how to fix some minor problems automatically in flutter mainly null check

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently upgraded my flutter project, Now in upgraded version there is null check function i am looking for any terminal code which can auto fix this problem. Is there any ?
i used dart `fix --dry-run` but it did not work
Thanks
[image: check image to make it clear what i want to say]

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this article [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/migrating-flutter-project-null-safety/) for more detail on that.
but running `dart migrate` in your project root should work